# Where can I get S. Heymann's GPU Implementation of SIFT Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, opengl, image-processing, sift

S. Heymann implemented SIFT algorithm on GPU in 2007, his paper is here
http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg/Papers_2007/Full/G03-full.pdf

Now I need to run his code for a comparison with my implementation. It seems his code is accessible since I read some papers which ran Heymann's implementation and did some analysis. However, I google it for days and just can not find Heymann's code or executable program. Can anybody tell me where I can find it?

Comment: Email the author and ask. Most researchers are happy to share their work (provided there are no legal or licensing issues.)

Comment: I sent an email 3 days ago, no reply...

Comment: Based on the publication record, it looks like Sebastian Heymann was a student and has probably since moved on.  There's someone matching the same name making an [image processing iPhone app](http://www.recolor.info/), which sounds like the kind of thing someone like that might get into.  Can't hurt to try?